# Moodle upload form for user upload

Tags: php, plugins, moodle, fgetcsv

I want to bulk upload users in the moodle plugin face-to-face, using .csv. 
The user upload has to take place in the session and be made by admin or manager. 
Using the file picker element from the File API

```
$mform->addElement('filepicker', 'userfile', get_string('file'), null,
               array('maxbytes' => $maxbytes, 'accepted_types' => '*'));
```

Then I need to extract this data and show the names, emails etc. in the attendees list and then in reports. Is `fgetcsv` the right choise?:

```
    $fields=fgetcsv($filehandle,0,$this->config->delimiter);
var_dump($fields)
$data=array();
while($row=fgetcsv($filehandle,0,$this->config->delimiter))
{
  $data_row->startdate=$row[0] 
  $data_row->enddate=$row[0]
  $data_row->room=$row[0]
  $data_row->status=$row[0]
  $data_row->firstname=$row[0]
  $data_row->lastname=$row[0]
  $data_row->username=$row[0]
  $data_row->useremail=$row[0]
  $data_row->attendance=$row[0]
  $data_row->signupdate=$row[0]
  array_push($data,$data_row)
  $DB->insert_record('facetoface',$data_row, false);
}
```

There isn't a plugin with user upload function in face-to-face sessions, nor there is something similar. 
Where to place the right code lines (in the different files of the plugin), or better said, which is the right way to proceed?
I would preffer to make a custom plugin, if that is easier,just need a guidence for the structure of it. The functionality is still similar to face-to-face, the sessions atendees are just uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to bulk upload users in Totara.

https://github.com/totara/seedlings/tree/totara-seedlings-2.7/mod/facetoface

But for your plugin you might want to use the `csv_import_reader` class

For an example have a look at `/admin/tool/uploaduser/index.php`

Comment: The bulk upload doesn't suite me, it has to take place in the f2f session and there to be synced with the the user data, in order to make reports from it. 
Thanks for the tip, I will try `csv_import_reader`. Does it have to be placed in  the f2f/session.php ?